# WP-CLI is unable to update password

Tags: wp-cli, password

I execute following command to change password for admin user from command line: `wp user update admin --user_pass="mynewpassword" --allow-root`
I got following error message:

> WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ''wp_poststats_visits'' at line 1 for query DROP
>   TABLE IF EXISTS 'wp_poststats_visits' made by
>   include('phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/boot-phar.php'),
>   include('phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/wp-cli.php'),
>   WP_CLI\bootstrap, WP_CLI\Bootstrap\LaunchRunner->process,
>   WP_CLI\Runner->start, WP_CLI\Runner->load_wordpress,
>   require('wp-settings.php'),
>   include_once('/plugins/wp-post-real-time-statistics/index.php'),
>   PostStatsHelper::uninstall

Information about system:

wp cli info
OS:     Linux 4.13.0-38-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 14 15:20:44 UTC 2018 x86_64
Shell:  /bin/bash
PHP binary:    /usr/bin/php7.1
PHP version:    7.1.17-0ubuntu0.17.10.1
php.ini used:  /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini

Comment: I'd guess there's a plugin that's causing you grief. `wp user update` shouldn't have to `DROP TABLE` to work. Do you have a plugin installed called "poststats" or something along those lines?

Comment: @PatJ : Yes, I have a plugin with this name.